# money count denomination C++

Tags: c++, currency

So my project is to develop an application where the user enters an amount (Ex. 65.67) and the output prints how many dollars, quarters, dime, nickels, and pennies make up the total (Example would be $5.52 is 5 dollars, 2 quarters and 2 pennies. Below I have left the block of code that deals with the calculation of the total. The dollars and quarters are getting distributed properly, but dimes, nickels and pennies are not.My logic is off and any advice will be greatly appreciated. I'm using windows 8.1, Code::Blocks IDE.

```
    // Calculations for money denomination//
    float dollar = floor(total);
        total = total-dollar;
    float quarter = floor(total/.25);
        total= total -(quarter*.25);
    float dime = floor(total/.1);
        total = total-(dime*.1);
    float nickel = floor(total/.05);
        total = total-(total*.05);
    float penny = floor(total/.01);
        total = total-(total*.01);
```

Comment: Why are you using `float` instead of an integer type?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Beta to answer your question, it's just flawed logic on my part. I'm still pretty new to programming. That's why I'm seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

Working with currency values should be done using integers because you can't guarantee that floating point values round properly when performing computation actions on them.

Basically you should use the smallest possible unit of money (cents) and manage all money values in those units. When displaying values, you would then convert to a proper format that the user expects.

Comment: Ok so I should use integers. so say I had the number 6567  then divided it by 100 (so 65.67 ) how do I keep the remaining .67 and turn that to an integer?

Comment: @killingerr You should *not* divide it by 100. Just work with 6567.

Comment: Well the issue is that I need to work with a decimal at the beginning.

Comment: @killingerr You need to? Why? (Input? Take it as string instead of number and make the conversion manually)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the advice everyone, here is what I ended up doing. Not the most elegant way I'm sure, but it gets the job done.

```
/// This states variables as well as evolving tally of dollar amount ///

int _total = (total*100)+.5; 
int dollar = _total/100;
 _total = _total%100;
int quarter = _total/25;
 _total= _total%25;
int dime = _total/10;
 _total = _total%10;
int nickel = _total/5;
 _total = _total%5;
int penny = _total/1;
 _total = _total%1;
```

Comment: The first line is not what you want.

Comment: Read the Goldberg link above.

Comment: The code works for its intended purpose, so while the link you provided is important it is beyond the scope of my project